# Rank 1 Cholesky decomposition update for sparse matrix with eigen/cholmod?

Tags: c++, eigen

I've a set of linked problems where I want to compute the Cholesky decomposition of a problem
k by combining two previous partial solutions, the solution for problem k is the concatenation of the two partial solutions plus some rank one update. My matrix is sparse, so basically I want a `cholupdate` like function for a sparse matrix. From my reading of the doc, I understand that such a function is not available in eigen, but there is a `cholmod_updown` function in `CHOLMOD` which seems to be exactly what I want. Is there a way to use this function through the `CholmodSupport` Module of `Eigen` ? Or another solution to do that?